# Generating Dynamic ui:include with generic managed bean

Tags: jsf

i have ui:include which i pass page name as parameter

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="recApp">
                        <ui:include src="#{recordPreviewBean.pageName}"></ui:include>
                    </div>
```

and i pass param like

```
if (selectedReply.getRecord().getRecordType() == 143) {
        pageName = "./letter.xhtml";
        letterBean.setMessage("Hello From Bean");
    }
```

but this in the same managed bean ,, now i will separate this ui:include in other page and will include page with parameterized bean  ,,, i attached image include scenario ... 
[Here is the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUW3V.png)

i want help in how to solve problem . so i am not expert java developer

thanks in advance

Comment: What is "*generic managed bean*"? A managed bean like a generic Java class is not available.

Comment: @ManagedBean
public class ProductsBean extends CrudBean<Product> {
    // ...
}

Comment: It is a managed bean extending a generic class. The managed bean itself cannot be generic (the type information would not be available at run-time) unless it is a dependent scoped (default) CDI managed bean.